# IIS and URL Rewrite for landing pages and simple URLs

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

Right now we have a bunch of extra directories with an index.htm in them that handle redirects to pages within our application.  Instead of littering our folder structure with these, is there a way to us URL rewrite to redirect a user without completely breaking 404 errors?

For example,

```
domain.com/login
```

Would redirect to

```
domain.com/user/accountLogin.htm
```

Or

```
domain.com/happypartnercompany
```

Could go to

```
domain.com/partners/about.xyz?partner=123
```

Comment: Those are simplest rewrite rules you can write with IIS URL Rewrite module, so did you even try? And what is "without completely breaking 404 errors"?

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly. when do you need a 404 error? or do you just want to redirect `domain.com/login` to the url below?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for a simple example, this is what I ended up doing:

```
<rule name="members" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^members*$" ignoreCase="true" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="index.xyz?m=home/members/list" />
</rule>
```

And to actually redirect the user:

```
<rule name="member_signup_1" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^sefcu*$" ignoreCase="true" />
   <action type="Redirect" url="index.xyz?m=signup/enroll&#38;partnerid=8532" />
</rule>
```

Ampersands must be escaped with `&#38;` in the URL.